# Move array in array down

Tags: spacing, arrays

I have the following code

```
\begin{array}{rl}
\textbf{fetcher} : \mathcal{T} &\to \mathcal{T} \\
(P_{\star}, w) &\mapsto \bigcup \limits_{p \in P_{\star}} \left(
{\setstretch{1.25}
\begin{array}{llll}
    best_{b_{R}} \big(& \big( R(p), &w_{R} \cdot \textbf{rank}_{R(p)} \big)&\big)  \ \cup \\
    best_{b_{C}} \big(& \big( C(p), &w_{C} \cdot \textbf{rank}_{C(p)} \big)&\big)  \ \cup \\
    best_{b_{A}} \big(& \big( A(p), &w_{A} \cdot \textbf{rank}_{A(p)} \big)&\big) 
\end{array}}
\right)
\end{array}
```

which results in

[image: Output]

I would however rather have it look like so:

[image: Goal]

I am not sure if `array` is the best choice for this, but I did not find any better way. Is there a way to move the second array down, or should I rather use something else?

Comment: use \begin{array}[t] so it aligns on the top row and remove the \left( \right) if you don't want them, as in the second image.

Comment: so easy! would you care to make this an actual answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want `array`, but `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\functionnameX}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\newcommand{\functionnameY}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\best}{\functionnameX{best}}
\newcommand{\rank}{\functionnameY{rank}}
\newcommand{\fetcher}{\functionnameY{fetcher}}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
\fetcher\colon \mathcal{T} &\to \mathcal{T} \\
(P_{\star}, w)             &\mapsto 
  \bigcup_{p \in P_{\star}}
  \begin{aligned}[t]
    \Bigl[&\best_{b_{R}} \bigl((R(p), w_{R} \cdot \rank_{R(p)})\bigr) \cup {} \\
    &\best_{b_{C}} \bigl((C(p), w_{C} \cdot \rank_{C(p)})\bigr) \cup {}\\
    &\best_{b_{A}} \bigl((A(p), w_{A} \cdot \rank_{A(p)})\bigr)\Bigr]
  \end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

Note `\bigl` or `\Bigr` in front of opening delimiters, `\bigr` or `\Bigr` for closing ones. I have some doubts about the double parentheses for the argument of *best*.

Note also how one can obtain uniform appearance of function names by using appropriate definitions in the preamble. Use better names than `\functionnameX` or `\functionnameY` so to give them some semantics that help in choosing one or the other.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I did not now about `aligned`, I only tried with `align` but got an error when nesting. The double parentheses are there because the argument of _best_ is a tuple.

Comment: @fabian789 oh no! see what you have done:-) http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15921306#15921306

Comment: haha I'm sorry! But the square brackets were just too juicy :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `\begin{array}[t]` so it aligns on the top row and remove the `\left( \right)` if you don't want them, as in the second image. (If you wanted to put brackets around a top aligned array then the `delarray` package can help.)